# Combine two alleles to genotype locus?

Tags: sequence-alignment, fasta, radseq

I have a following fasta (produced by stacks populations):

```
>CLocus_10056_Sample_934_Locus_12529_Allele_0 [sample_934; groupI, 49712]
TGCAGGCCCCAGGCCACGCCGTCTGCGGCAGCGCTGGAAGGAGGCGGTGGAGGAGGCGGCCAACGGCTCCCTGCCCCAGAAGGCCGAGTTCACCG
>CLocus_10056_Sample_934_Locus_12529_Allele_1 [sample_934; groupI, 49712]
TGCAGGCCCCAGGCCACGCCGTCTGCGGCAGCGTTGGAAGGAGGCGGTGGAGGAGGCGGCCAACGGCTCCCTGCCCCAGAAGGCCGAGTTCACCG
```

as both alleles are represented separetely, I want to combine both genes using IUPAC nucleotide code.
Is there a tool for it or is it more useful to do it via a custom script?